# try add a criteria with include for telemetry processor in ApplicationInsights V3 (java) Codeless Approach is not working?

Tags: java, include, azure-application-insights, criteria, processor

I have to add a new attribute facility on all logs with a filter to name attributes with value toto value, but I don't know why it s not working
maybe including criteria is not working?
I use this tutorial
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-telemetry-processors.

my conf json and my jar application insights-agent-3.4.15.jar

```
{
  "connectionString": "secret",
  "role": {
    "name": "dev"
  },
  "preview": {
    "processors": [
      {
        "type": "attribute",
        "include": {
          "matchType": "strict",
          "attributes": [
            {
              "key": "toto",
              "value": "valuetoto"
            }
          ]
        },
        "actions": [
          {
            "key": "opfacility",
            "value": "opcpf",
            "action": "insert"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

on my insight transaction search result
I have
Properties
Telemetry type  trace

custom properties
toto valuetoto

why is my processor not working?
I try without including criteria and its work
the processor add my new attribute but why the include doesn't work
anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> I try without including criteria and its work the processor add my new attribute but why the include doesn't work anything wrong?

I also referred the above documentation demonstrates how to configure an attribute processor with an "include" condition to match specific attributes and values, but the processor failed.

Configure an **ApplicationInsights.xml** file to you application check below.

```xml
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
  <InstrumentationKey>YourInstrumentationKey</InstrumentationKey>
  <!-- Other configuration settings -->
  
  <TelemetryProcessors>
    <Add Type="com.example.CustomAttributeProcessor">
      <Include>
        <MatchType>Strict</MatchType>
        <Attributes>
          <Add Key="toto" Value="valuetoto" />
        </Attributes>
      </Include>
      <Actions>
        <Add Key="opfacility" Value="opcpf" Action="Insert" />
      </Actions>
    </Add>
  </TelemetryProcessors>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

- The telemetry processing logic specified in the configuration files is applied to the telemetry data before it's sent to Application Insights.
- Once the new/updated config file is ready try to re-deploy the JAR files or other relevant resources for the changes

**Result:**
[image]

[image]

Comment: the purpose is not to show valuetoto but  it s to add facility key with his value  when you have a logger with map (toto,valuetoto).